# fixing the container width and height and making image responsive to the container using Query

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Width and height of the div should be fixed

image inside the fixed div should be responsive and should not exceed the container height.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;` to the image should work. The image should fit into the fixed-size container div:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" style="height: 100%">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Testcase</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">

 <div style="border: 1px solid red; margin: auto auto; width: 90%; height: 90%; overflow: hidden;">
  <img style="display: block; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; " src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is important, that in the image-tag, you do not specify width and height attributes.